# remote powershell scripts on windows not running through python script in linux

Tags: linux, python-2.7, subprocess, powershell-2.0, paramiko

I have a python script written using paramiko and pysphere.this script is in linnux box.i have some powershell scripts on windows machine which i have to run one after the other(after each script ends obviously),but the point here is through my pythonscript it is not running the powershell scripts on windows machine.Kindly help.
PS;i have to run python script fromlinux and powershell scriupts on windows.
Here is a snippet of code for running powershell scripts:

```
target_vm1 = connect_Esxi_Server(return_list[0])

print "Again connected to vm:" + return_list[0]

target_vm1.login_in_guest(vmUser,vmPass)

list_scripts = target_vm1.list_files(VM_SCRIPT_LOCATION)

for f in list_scripts:

    size = f['size']
    **if size <> 0:**

        paths = f['path']

        print paths

        #for all_scripts in paths:
        *****print "script running is :" , paths*****
        path_l = os.path.join(VM_SCRIPT_LOCATION + '\\'+ paths)
        *****print path_l*****
        run_script =            
subprocess.Popen([r'c:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe',". path_l"], shell=True)

        result = run_script.wait()
        print "result is:", result
```

I doubt whether subprocess will work.

Please note that the bold prints given above are giving the correct script to run.there are many powershell scriptsinside the fo;der,so looping throught it and running each one of them.

***Any help would be appreciated,this thing is eating my heads off.....argghhhhhhhh..***

Cheers,
NJ

Answer (score 2):

I run powershell commands directly using paramiko:

```
import paramiko 

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('10.10.0.2', username='vipul', password='password')

cmd = "powershell -InputFormat none -OutputFormat text echo Hello"

stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(cmd)

print stdout.readlines()
```

Here 10.10.0.2 is my windows machine. Using cygwin sshd server for ssh.